# No notifications when sending apprequest

Tags: facebook, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“apprequests” dialog reports success, recipients receive nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259517/apprequests-dialog-reports-success-recipients-receive-nothing)

I am developing a facebook app, and one of the main functions, is to allow a user to send a apprequest to another user, notifying him that he has been challenged.

However, in the past couple of days, it seems something has gone wrong. For some reason, i can send the apprequest just fine, but the diamond does not show at the top of the screen. I checked in the Graph API Explorer, and sure enough, the apprequest are present in there, but the notification never pops up.

Also, the game request does add up on the left side of my mains facebook page, but when i click the game request, none of them are shown?

Is this caused by facebook messing around with the request 2.0 stuff? or could it be my code that creates a "wrong" request? this is an example taken form teh Graph Api Explorer

{
      "id": "10150308326517343",
      "application": {
        "name": "appname",
        "id": "277628332248286"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "Jacob Harpøth Hansen",
        "id": "506232342"
      },
      "from": {
        "name": "Jacob Harpøth Hansen",
        "id": "506232342"
      },
      "message": "text",
      "created_time": "2011-09-30T09:01:29+0000",
      "type": "apprequest"
    }

Answer (score 2):

Do you have checked option "App on Facebook" in your applecation settings section "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"? Because you can't sending apprequest to just Tabbed application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notification for app-generated requests - only for user-generated.

Comment: Facebook's [iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels) clearly shows notifications for `apprequests`, but I don't see them either. App's bookmark badge does show the number next to it, just like @JacobHarpøthHansen described.