# "apprequests" dialog reports success, recipients receive nothing

Tags: ios, facebook, apprequests, facebook-ios-sdk

Using the Facebook iOS SDK I can display a dialog with apprequests and send it. Delegate method `-dialogDidComplete:` gets called, but the recipient(s) receive no notification or request of any kind. If they have the app authorized, Facebook.app (for iOS) will display a number of pending requests next to the app bookmark, but notification jewel doesn't get updated and notification is nowhere to be found and Facebook.app doesn't display any push notifications.

I have followed Facebook's own [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels) for this and even tried with their own sample project Hackbook, but I get the same result every time.

Am I missing something in [app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) or is this simply not working as described in the (poor) documentation?

I can see Path app implemented this and it works pretty well on my devices with my accounts so I guess I really did skip something. Adding a bounty in hope of a solution.

Comment: can you tell me how you got the requests dialog to show? i haven't even gotten that far. -- never mind, i found it "apprequests" is the dialog you need. thanks!

Comment: just implemented this and i have the same problem. maybe it only works if you app is in production?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found an explanation that helped me fix this here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8211249/184561

When a user clicks on an app request, Facebook takes them to your Facebook canvas page. If you don't have a canvas page, the requests don't show up.

As soon as I added a canvas url (one that didn't even work), the requests started showing up.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.  I was sending requests out, and trying to receive them on Mobile devices (through Safari and the iOS Facebook app) with no luck.  I had to add a Mobile Web URL to my app.

Comment: Where to set this canvas URl? I cant see it on the settings page

Comment: @114100웃 Sorry, this was from 3 years ago. I don't remember and it's probably different now.

Answer (score 2):

,Please make sure you have registered you App as "App On Facbook" within your FB app settings.And your Facebook App needs to have a Canvas URL defined. The URL doesn't even need to be valid, it just needs to be defined in the Settings of the App. I have done things in same way and i am getting the Notification of App request in my Facebook Notifications,I hope you can get The App Request Notification in your Facebook Notification.

Comment: Where to set this canvas URl? I cant see it on the settings page