# Sending facebook business page invitation via request dialog, recipient receive nothing

Tags: javascript, facebook, invitation

I'm new to facebook development and have done a lot of research and start getting my head around, i've come to realised that many coding implementation available online were using FBML which will be discontinue very soon, not much luck to find resources or tutorial for the iframe methodology.

At this stage what am i trying to do is to put a button on a business page when user clicks a friends invitation pop up will be appear on the screen. What i found from developer.facebook.com was the following link:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

by using the request2.0 javascript sdk to trigger the pop up and send invitation to users. I followed the tutorial as stated and has been successfully get the pop up dialog box shows, after selected friends that i want to invite i clicked send then the window closed. (i  used the function "sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector()" and did nothing on requestCallBack as shown from the example.) and the X account did not receive any invitation or notification of my invitation at all.

I also read:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259517/apprequests-dialog-reports-success-recipients-receive-nothing)
and 
[Link 2](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7630783/why-it-shows-app-requests-1-but-no-requests-listed-in-the-app-pages-on-facebo)

I tried to understand but i got confused by the mix of php and javascript in certain stage.

Would be appreciate if anyone could provide me some explanation (or links for me to read if you are lazy :-D)

***Note: Please be aware that i'm not asking a question without doing any research. I have experienced with asked by a developer/user to create my question instead of asking under his post. And thats why i wrote this.

Thank you for your time to read my post.

Comment: Hi, as far as I can tell, you can't use requests for pages, only for apps. Your best bet might be to use the send dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently tried the same thing as you did and i've been successfully sending request but whenever user click on the invitation link, it directs user to a page with full canvas like at apps interface. I got this work by attaching the url into canvas under apps setting at the configuration page